# Automate making arrays with for loop in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

I would like to know if it is possible to automate making arrays using Python (3.4). I would like it to be able to do something like this:

```
for i in range(theRange)
    array.i = [0]*arrayLength

    array.i[0] = someValue
    array.i[1] = someOtherValue
    ....
```

so that there will be `theRange` number of arrays that can be differentiated.

Comment: Yeah I think that may have solved my problem. I'll check the "That solved my problem!" button when I'm sure. Thanks, Matt!

Comment: How about ``[[j for j in range(3)] for i in range(4)]``?